# Add html inside draggable div css box

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I have this code to generate a /draggable/ css box:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
<style>
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  // find the element that you want to drag.
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  /* listen to the touchMove event,
  every time it fires, grab the location
  of touch and assign it to box */
  box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    // grab the location of touch
    var touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
    // assign box new coordinates based on the touch.
    box.style.left = touchLocation.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = touchLocation.pageY + 'px';
  })
  /* record the position of the touch
  when released using touchend event.
  This will be the drop position. */
  box.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    // current box position.
    var x = parseInt(box.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(box.style.top);
  })
}
</script>
```

I would like to **add an html code**

```
<iframe src="https://alceawisteria.codeberg.page/Diarykeepers_Homepage/stash/webamp.html" frameBorder="no" width=500px height=250></iframe>
```

***into the draggable box*.**

(but putting it inside the 'box div' will just not render it.)
Is there anything I need to heed specifically to make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can place the iframe inside the container element, and set its position to absolute. After that you can adjust its position using the same coordinates that you're using to move the box

Try this :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
    <iframe id="myiframe" src="https://alceawisteria.codeberg.page/Diarykeepers_Homepage/stash/webamp.html" frameBorder="no" width="500px" height="250"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#myiframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
  
  box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
    var x = touchLocation.pageX;
    var y = touchLocation.pageY;
    
    box.style.left = x + 'px';
    box.style.top = y + 'px';
    iframe.style.left = x + 'px';
    iframe.style.top = y + 'px';
  })
  
  box.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    var x = parseInt(box.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(box.style.top);
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm. But now it is no longer **draggable** :(

Comment: Isn't it due to the size of the box which might be too small ? You can try to change the width and height of #box to 500px both